# TypeError: evaluate_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n_input'

Tags: python

```
    enterscores=evaluate_model(test,14)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-c17f426490bf> in <module>()
----> 1 scores=evaluate_model(test,14)

TypeError: evaluate_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n_input'
```

Comment: If "evaluate_model" belongs to a library you should add the appropriate tag. If not, show the definition of the function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.